# Responsive sliding on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, slider

You guys already helped me out a lot, I hope you can help me with this question to.

This is my website so far: http://stilld.nl/test/

Everything is working pretty good (need to do a lot of tidying up in my code though).

Please scroll down to the portfolio part. Click an item and the details appear beneath the portfolio. PERFECT!

PROBLEM: size you browser down to mobile format. Click a portfolio item. it doesn't scroll down far enough, because my portfolio items are now displayed beneath each other. They take up much more vertical space now!

WHAT I WANT: Is there a way to make code responsive? So something like: if screen size is smaller then 600 px THEN slide down 500px on click.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".portfolio").click(function () {
    if ($('#'+$(this).attr('target')).is(':visible')){
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideUp();        
    } else {
        $('.description').slideUp(); 
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown();        
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#targetWrapper').offset().top + 50 }, 600);
    }

});
$(".close").click(function () {
    $('.description').slideUp();        
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#p_img').offset().top }, 600);
});
```

});

Comment: You question must be how to detect window size? and its answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306933/how-to-detect-window-size-and-then-do-something-with-jquery-switch-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the `offset` with either jQuery's [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or jQuery's [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

What you could do for example is:

```
$(".portfolio").click(function () {    

    var offSetTarget = $('.description').position().top;
    var scrollExtra = 0;

    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: offSetTarget + scrollExtra

    }, 600);
});
```

Where you can determine how much `extra` you want to scroll.

For example if you want to scroll just above the `.portfolio`, you can add: `scrollExtra = -10;` . Or if you want to scroll halfway, you could do: `scrollExtra = $('.portfolio').height()/2;`

I prepared a working example for you [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/q4zua/).

To prove that it actually works, you can play with the window size [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q4zua/embedded/result/).

I hope that answers your question. Good luck!

### Update

To implement it into your example, we would have to determine where to scroll to.

For illustrational purposes, I have chosen to do this with the divs `#alldescriptions` and `#port_img1` in this example.

The jQuery for your website would then be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".portfolio").click(function () {

    var offSetTarget = $('#alldescriptions').position().top;
    var scrollExtra = 0;

    if ($('#'+$(this).attr('target')).is(':visible')){
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideUp();        
    } else {
        $('.description').slideUp(); 
        $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown();        
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: offSetTarget + scrollExtra }, 600);
    }

  });
  $(".close").click(function () {
      $('.description').slideUp();        
      $('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#port_img1').position().top }, 600);
  });
});
```

Again, mind you that you can alter the exact scrolling location by giving `var scrollExtra` a different value.

You can find an implementation of this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4A9zf/) and a live fullscreen example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4A9zf/embedded/result/).

Please play around with the window size again so you can see it actually works with every screensize. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, I'm getting somewhere! But I'm not really sure how to implement your code in mine... I'm still a noob with this type of coding..

Comment: Haha really..? Ok.. I will implement it in yours then.. Geef me een minuutje ;)

Comment: Haha, dankjewel! Ik zie het graag tegemoet.

Comment: @user1737979: Please check update. Ik hoop dat ik nu je vraag heb beantwoord :)

Comment: Thx! I tried implementing, but what happens is that the page scrolls up i stead of scrolling to the details.

Comment: When I use scrollextra I can adjust the height to where to scroll but that doesn't solve the problem, because that's a fixed number... So when on mobile, it just scrolls the scrollextra, and that's not far enough.

Comment: `scrollextra` is merely for adjusting the scrollheight, the `var offSetTarget = $('#alldescriptions').position().top;` determines the actual scrolling position. If it scrolls up then it means that the `target.position().top` is not calculated to the top of the body but to the top of some wrapper, because in my example it does work. So play around a little with the `$('#alldescriptions').position().top` and you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah, I think what's going wrong. The #alldescriptions should work for me to, but #alldescriptions will appear on click. So it's not visible yet. OnClick two things happen: the details (#alldescriptions) appear and the site scrolls to #alldescriptions. So maybe your solution doesn't see #alldescription because it's not there yet.... Hope you understand. It would be more easy in Dutch to explain, haha!

Comment: Solution would be that the code lets the details appear first and after that scrolls down to the #alldescriptions, because then it's there.

Comment: Can you give me the jQuery code where `alldescriptions` appears `onClick`? (your site is offline)

Comment: Jean-Paul, could you take another look at the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the inner width of the screen and then set variables for the offset.

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 600) {
    var offSet = 500;}


  else{
        var offSet = 600;}
```

Then replace this in your code:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#targetWrapper').offset().top + 50 }, offSet);
```

BUT.... if you want to simplify your code, you could use CSS Transitions. Then just use jQuery to add and remove a class that triggers the Transition, using media querys to change the offset. It would also have less overhead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not good enough to understand what you mean... Could you be more specific? 

An other solution would be when you click the sliding doesn't goes down pixel but just scrolls down to the wrapper containing the details. Do you understand what I mean? 

How do I need to adjust the code to slide down to a anchor point?